# How can I solve deadlock issue in SQL Server in my scenario ?

Tags: sql-server

Problem: when 'EXEC TEST' query is executed in production system, it triggers deadlock error. `abc` table's data is updated but data is not inserted into `tbl_newtable` due deadlock victim. So what could be the solution to prevent a deadlock?

[image]

Comment: It looks like homework, so you need to tell us what you are trying to do up to now and then ask for help. This is not a site for making your homework instead of you.

Comment: thanks for you kind replay..Bogdan Bogdanov ,i am asking for help and this scenario is small footprint of my production system's stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

The textbook solutions to deadlocks is to (1) minimize execution time by optimizing the query's performance, (2) apply locks in the same order everywhere, (3) minimize locking, as @Gazmend suggests, and (4) implement a proper try-catch to re-run a deadlock victim's transaction.

I've [blogged](http://sqlsunday.com/2013/03/03/deadlocks/) about deadlocks if you want a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be to use a parameter for the second procedure and provide the "name" value from the first procedure as a parameter.This is to avoid querying uncommited data...

One other option would be to allow "read uncommited"...

Comment: Don't use read uncommitted unless you're ok with incorrect results.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel, don't use "read uncommitted"... it does not mean that you will have incorrect results ... but you should do a bit more work to make sure that you have correct results.